# GraphQL parser string literal

Tags: javascript, syntax, graphql, react-apollo

Recently I have started learning GraphQL with `react-apollo` and I found this piece of code which is interesting for me.

```
const ALL_LINKS_QUERY = gql`
query AllLinksQuery {
  allLinks {
    id
    createdAt
    url
    description
  }
}
`
```

How can be string literal used so in JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gql` is an example of a [template tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_template_literals). From the docs:

> A more advanced form of template literals are tagged template
>   literals. Tags allow you to parse template literals with a function.

Tags are a new feature introduced with ES6, but their really just functions that take the template literal as a parameter and return something else. The `gql` tag takes the template literal with your query and parses it into Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) format, which is what the Apollo client uses under the hood.

Comment: Basically we could do so gql(`template`)? :)

Comment: Actually, you should make sure you utilize the same syntax as in the code sample you pasted. `gql´my template literal here´` !== `gql(´my template literal here´)`. In the first one, `gql` is passed the template literal. In the second one, `gql` is actually passed the *string* that results from the template literal. It's a small distinction, but an important one to how the template literal is parsed!